# IE Icons not round

Tags: internet-explorer, icons

In firefox and chrome my footer icons are round but in IE they are not. 
Can anyone help?

Site is here. [CLICK HERE](http://ceskakoruna.com/)

Comment: on which version of ie is not looking rounded

Comment: Which IE ? Look at the documentation for [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ie` hacks for `border-radius` use like this

```
.rounded-corners {
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

and here is the link for download `.htc` file
http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because IE 8 doesn't support border-radius property. Read this. [Border Radius](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)